# How to layout text and Image correctly

Tags: html, css, image, browser

I am trying to structure some text and images so that it will render correctly on a mobile device.

When viewing on a normal desktop browser it looks as it should - the top left corner has the name in text, followed by an image and the main logo is centred in the top of the page

[image]

However, when loading on a mobile device - the images start to overlap one another. This can be seen below;

[image]

I have tried adding the text and logo in the top left to a `div` tag and pinning that to the top left as follows;

```
div.upperleftlogo {
    position : fixed;
    top      : 0px;
    left    : 0px;
}

<!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">

        <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="upperleftlogo">
               <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Swifte</a></h1>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" ><img class="scaledimage" src="swifte/images/AvailableAppStore.png" width="108" height="30" id="appStoreLogo"/></a>
            </div>
        <!-- Nav -->
```

But this still doesn't solve the issue.

In regards to the main application / website logo, I really don't know how to solve the overlap there.

Would someone be able to offer some help.

Thanks

Comment: Tough to say without more code... try changing the position around (relative, absolute) and/or adding a margin-top: to your larger logo (in your media query) that seems to be getting in the way

Comment: Use media queries look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries, and this http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/, and this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp. Using media queries you can position, size, etc your content, as you would in CSS normally, for multiple screen sizes