# Firefox will not download font

Tags: html, css, firefox

I was directed towards using media queries after I raised a question earlier - this can be seen here [How to layout text and Image correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430268/how-to-layout-text-and-image-correctly). Since then I have had some real success with modifying my website and i would like to thank the posters in that thread.

Now however I am facing a new issues=.

Custom font in firefox

No matter what file type I try I just can't get my custom font to work in Firefox. I am using firefox version 31.0 and after googling it suggested I needed to use the .woff file type. This is my list of font faces declared;

```
@font-face {font-family: 'CustomFont';src: url('font/Pacifico.ttf'); 
@font-face {font-family: 'CustomFont';src: url('font/Pacifico.svg');
@font-face {font-family: 'CustomFont';src: url('font/Pacifico.woff');
```

Chrome works perfectly, as does safari so I am not sure why firefox wouldn't, does anyone have any idea? looking in to the developer log i can see the following error;

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "CustomFont" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147746065
source: http://secondstory.co.uk/swifte/css/swifte/font/Pacifico.ttf
```

Googling this has not really helped me tho

Comment: I just went to your site and it seems your fonts are being loaded from the wrong path in much of your style.css. It says `/swifte/font/....ttf` everywhere.

Comment: how strange, the font i am concerned with (in original post) has an extra swifte in the middle of the url, how does it work on other browsers then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your styles.css (I went to your site) there is a line:

```
<!--@font-face {font-family: 'CustomFont';src: url('swifte/font/Pacifico.ttf'); /* For Internet Explorer 6+ */}-->
```

If you remove that line, it works in Firefox.

As a general rule, use c-style comments in CSS files. SGML-style comments are invalid.